# Get tkinter Spinbox value inside a function

Tags: python, tkinter, spinbox

I have to display a number of wireshark packets and the user can select the particular packet to view the information. For that, I have used one function called SelectedFilterSearch() to display packets of the selected filter.

The user will select the particular packet from a Spinbox, which will display when the number of packets is greater than zero with a command button to display. 
I am unable to get spinbox selected value. Can anyone help?
Below is my code. I am not using class.

```
def SelectedFilterSearch():
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture(pktfname.get(), display_filter= fltrname.get())

def display():
    print(selectedspin.get())

numpkts = 0

for i in cap:
    numpkts = numpkts + 1
if numpkts < 1:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Selected filter not available")
else:
    dispString = "There are " + str(numpkts) + " packet available. Please select a packet to display"
    selectedspin = Spinbox(top_right, from_=0, to=numpkts, width=3).grid(row=4, column=10)
    TFLDisplayLpkts = tkinter.Label(top_right, font=("Courier", 9), text=dispString, background="cyan").grid(row=3, column=10)
    TFLDisplayB = tkinter.Button(top_right, text = "Display", command = display).grid(row=5, column=10)
```

Comment: Thanks to Bryan for his editing and Thanks to Robert for the solution. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can create variable to store selected value. See how I'm dealing with this problem.

```
def display():
    print(my_spinbox_var.get())
my_spinbox_var=IntVar()
my_spinbox=Spinbox(top_right,from_0,to=numpkts,width=3,textvariable=my_spinbox_var)
my_spinbox.grid(row=4,column=10)
```

Please do not hesitate to contact me.

Robert